# Can a prepositional phrase modify a noun when there is a verb between the noun and the prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, modifiers

For example,

> Forecasts have emerged of heavy rain.
>
> A structurally sound argument was presented of the characteristics and implications of economic recessions.

Is the prepositional phrase modifying "forecasts" or is it actually modifying the verb? I've heard sentences like this used before, but are they grammatically correct?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but that feels wrong to me.  `Forecasts of heavy rain have emerged` is the obvious correction.  If the question is, "is this the best way to write it", then my correction would be better. But as for "is this a possible way that is grammatically correct"- tbh I've no idea.

Comment: @nycynik I appreciate the answer; however, I'm not so much interested in better ways to write the example.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatically correct. I'd say that the PP "of heavy rain" is complement of "forecasts". It has probably been postposed to the end of the clause in order to receive a somewhat greater phonological prominence.

Comment: No, those prepositional clauses without a comma in front are modifying the verb. They are incorrectly written if the intention was to modify the noun, in which case they require a comma in front. For example, the first example is saying that from the heavy rain forecasts emerged. It is unlikely that someone wants to say that some forecasts came out of drops of water.

Comment: @mama This is an interesting way of looking at the problem. However, isn't it somewhat of a leap to assume that we mean "from" in the first example?

Comment: @johnnyodonnell That is what the phrase means if written without a comma. As you say they sound absurd. That is why they should have a comma.

Comment: @mama I'm not quite sure about that. I could see that as a possible interpretation, but we would then have to assume that the author meant to use "from" rather than "of".

Comment: Well, you are not sure if you are wrong, but you are. That is one of the main uses of a comma, separating an adjectival interrupting phrase.

Comment: No comma is required. This is a simple case of a PP being postposed to a position after the verb. It can't possibly be seen to be modifying the verb. The basic non-preposed order would be "Forecasts of heavy rain have emerged".

Comment: It's like "Tales were told of cabbages and kings".